# What UML relationship is in between class A and B, where A uses methods of B to create its instance and then uses it inside own (A's) class?

Tags: uml

What UML relationship is in between class A and B, where A uses methods of B in order to create its instance and then uses it inside own (A's) class?
Is it a dependency? e.g   A -----------> B

e.g how to depict relationship between Sender and Invite in the below code?

```
class Sender{

   public void sendInvite(){
     ....
     Invite i = Invite.getInstance();
     ....
   }

}

class Invite{
   ...
   public static Invite getInstance(){
     ...
   }
}
```

Note: once we return from method sendInvite() we do not store any link to class Invite anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it could be expressed as one of the [usage dependencies](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html). Draw a dashed arrow from `Sender` to `Invite`, label it with `«call»` or something similar and move on

Comment: @RUstar: you should accept this answer if you don't feel comfortable with an association.

Answer (score 1):

A (directed) association from Sender to Invite. Since you do not use a property but a local variable you must not use a role name for Invite. Further you likely have an association to self for Invite which (I guess) is used to retrieve the singleton instance inside `getInstance()`.

[image]

From Superstructures 2.1.1 about Association

> An association specifies a semantic relationship that can occur between typed instances. It has at least two ends represented by properties, each of which is connected to the type of the end. More than one end of the association may have the same type.
>
> An end property of an association that is owned by an end class or that is a navigable owned end of the association indicates that the association is navigable from the opposite ends; otherwise, the association is not navigable from the opposite ends.

... and Dependency:

> A dependency signifies a supplier/client relationship between model elements where the modification of the supplier may impact the client model elements. A dependency implies the semantics of the client is not complete without the supplier. The presence of dependency relationships in a model does not have any runtime semantics implications, it is all given in terms of the model-elements that participate in the relationship, not in terms of their instances.

Comment: as far as I know association is only when we have link from class A to class B... but this is the case only once in one method. If method is not called - then no link exists. Are you sure it is not dependency?

Comment: Well, I would say: feel free. You have a relation between both classes. The definition in SS2.1.1 (and following) is wishy washy enough to let you the freedom. A dependency is not as strong as an association. But what does "strong" mean? You can define it...